# Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js) while updating from ng 11 to ng 16

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack, build

TL;DR: While Updating my Angular Application, a strange error appeared. How to solve it?

Context:

After a long time, I finally updated my Angular 11 to an Angular 16 App.

As I went along, I got some errors, which where all fixable.

One error is left blocking my build, which I don't even know where to even start at.

```
./projects/configurator-frontend/src/lib/configurator-frontend.module.less?ngResource - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: The 'exportType' option with the 'css-style-sheet' or 'string' value requires the 'esModules' option to be enabled
```

Some facts:

- I'm working on an Library
- It has something to do with parsing LESS files of the Main Module of the Library
- If I remove the less file from the module styleUrls it works perfectly fine (all other less files are handled correctly)
- If I empty the file the error still appears
- If I copy the contents to another file, it works (so no connection to the less file it self
- If I create a new NG Project and introduce less on the module level, error appears again

My personal thoughs:

- It seems like something is not correctly setup within webpack (I did not diverge from ng default behavior - no custom Webpack etc.)

What I tried:

- Delete node_modules + package-lock.json
- Clear npm cache
- Updated Node + npm
- Updated all dependencies

I not very deep into webpack/node/npm, so I'm not even sure where to start. Any Ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Some additional infos:

```
Angular CLI: 16.2.5        
Node: 18.18.0              
Package Manager: npm 10.2.0
OS: win32 x64              

Angular: 16.2.8
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1602.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.2.5
@angular-devkit/core            16.2.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.2.5
@angular/cli                    16.2.5
@schematics/angular             16.2.5
ng-packagr                      16.2.3
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.1.6
zone.js                         0.13.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue, you are not allowed to have your less file called:

`[moduleName].module.less`

It has to be called anthing but the suffix `.module.less`

(As a personal addititon: This is one of the most disturbing behaviors, I ever saw)

Comment: For anyone else coming across this, it doesn't appear to be unique to Less files. This happened to me with my Sass `module-name.module.scss` files as well. I renamed them to `module-name.shared.scss` to fix it.